# Container/Child UIViewControllers and status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to get a parent view controller to display a child view controller's view. I've got the following in the parent's `viewDidLoad` :

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create child view controller
    [self setMenuController:[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:nil]];
    [self addChildViewController:[self menuController]];

    // move the child view down 30 pt
    CGRect frame = [[[self menuController] view] frame];
    frame.origin.y = 30;
    [[[self menuController] view] setFrame:frame];
    [[self menuController] setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];

    [[self view] addSubview:[[self menuController] view]];

    [[[self menuController] view] setNeedsLayout];
}
```

The child view controller's xib is simply a red view with a centered, partially transparent `UIImageView` (to see overlap).

If I disable the status bar in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, I get the following:

[image: No status bar]

If I enable the status bar, I get:

[image: Status bar]

With a status bar, the child controller's `UIView` is automatically adjusted to make room for where the status bar would be (since the image view is centered, that's 10 pts on top and bottom). Since this is a child view, it should always use the full size of the view controller's view regardless of whether the parent will have a status bar. Is there any way to achieve this besides resizing any child views to be 20 pixels bigger, or using a wrapper view in the child view controller?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting frame to menuController's view's bounds instead of its frame. Also, I'm not sure that you want setWantsFullScreen which should cause the view to underlap the status bar.

**After Edit:**

Try it like this, and see if this works.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self setMenuController:[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:nil]];
    [self addChildViewController:menuController];
    [menuController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    menuController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y +30, menuController.view.frame.size.width, menuController.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:menuController.view];
}
```

Comment: They both are the same, 0,0 / correct width, correct height. The setWantsFullScreen was one of the things I tried to keep the view from resizing, which did nothing but I figured to leave it in there for the example.

Comment: @Turch, I think you should be setting the origin to the superview's bounds.origin.y +30 (the frame.origin.y of the controller's view will be 20 if the status bar is showing if you check it in viewDidAppear). But I'm a little confuse about what's going on in your image. I've edited my post with how I think it should work. Note that I do it in viewDidAppear because the frames are not set yet in viewDidLoad.